# Publish ASP.net can't see assembly

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, iis-6

I have a very simple ASP.net application I am using to learn. I've developed it (two controls -- dropdown box and a datagrid, plus an EF class) on my laptop using a copy of the production db (this initial app is read-only) so I can minimize the variables I have to understand when I deploy it on my client's much more secure environment.

Since I'm using EF, I need .net4, of course. That was my first challenge. IIS had no application pool for .net4. Got that fixed (I think). Here's my Publication Package Page: 
[image]

Now, I'm getting something else strange... I've googled it and still don't understand. Perhaps someone can give me some advice.

[image: Actual Error Message]

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the `src` attribute with the path to the `CodeBehind` file inside your Page declarations. This should fix your issue.

The src attribute is put here:

```
<%@ Page ... Src="/path_to_BrowseWD.aspx.cs" ... %>
```

Comment: Konstantin, Thanks for your quick response. I am BRAND NEW at asp.net, so I'm not sure where to point the src= attribute. Isn't it the same as the CodeBehind attribute? I'll try some things. I have to say, this is pretty complex for a "wizzard" install. I assumed it'd be plug and play. Am I doing something wrong in the deployment configuration?

Comment: OK, I've determined the package doesn't seem to include the codebehind file. I searched the entire path starting with wwwroot and found no ".cs" files. I put the package configuration screen into the original question above. Have I coded something wrong?

Comment: @JimS-Indy Are you building a website or an application?

Comment: Again, remember I'm a noob. I chose "ASP.NET Empty Web Application". From what I read, that meant I could publish with a wizard and not have to deal with these issues. Perhaps that was my mistake... I've now used the package configuration to "add all files" to the publish, and the source file now appears in the main directory (c:\inetpub\wwwroot\BrowseWOs\BrowseWO.aspx.cs) but the parser still can't find it. I used intellisense to set src="~/BrowseWO.aspx".

Comment: @JimS-Indy A web application packages an assembly (DLL) upon deployment. Is the assembly deployed correctly?

Comment: Well, I don't know what I did, but I changed the <%page.... header back to what it was when I started this thread, then I checked "Mark as IIS application on destination" on the "Publish" popup. That seemed to work. Then, I had problems with SQL Server authentication, but I solved that pretty quickly. So, I'm in good shape now, though I have no idea why...I'll keep studying. And I thank all of you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Add this attribute to the first line CodeFile="BrowseWO.aspx.cs" and remove the CodeBehind attribute like this

Comment: <%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>